# mysql crashed, after start again, the new data lost, only old records of some day ago

Tags: mysql

I got a server restart, the mysql server seems crashed. 
After reboot, mysql database filled of old data for bug tracker.

Do you know how to fix this?
mysql error log as below

```
 131027 15:29:19 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 131027 15:29:19 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
 InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
 131027 15:29:19  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
 InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
 InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
 InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
 InnoDB: buffer...
 131027 15:29:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
 131027 15:29:25 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 320322004
 131027 15:29:25 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
 131027 15:29:25 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
 131027 15:29:25 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
 131027 15:29:26 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
 131027 15:29:26 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
 Version: '5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
 131027 15:29:34 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './bugtracker/mantis_bug_history_table' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
 131027 15:29:34 [Warning] Checking table:   './bugtracker/mantis_bug_history_table'
 131027 15:29:34 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.32/storage/myisam/ha_myisam.cc:912
 131027 15:29:34 [Warning] Recovering table: './bugtracker/mantis_bug_history_table'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how to fix this?

Yes, Apply the latest backup.

If you can not do that because you do not take backups - look please for a job where you are not responsible for managing data. Backups is "professional databases for beginner admins, day 1, hour 1". Fundamental Like not driving a car totally drunk level of fundamental.

That being said, this sounds "crazy". As in - I am sure you overlook something. This is not a behavior I would expect on a crash UNLESS it runs on a VM and was rolling back to a backup or fixed start state.... corruption DOES sometimes make things bad or result in lost data, but rarely in a consistent state some days back. I would investigate whether you have a larger problem. I remember a company loosing money because the (not so smart) admin had set up vm's to roll back to a known state in case of a backup... which wiped access keys that can not be recovered to some serious funds (http://siliconangle.com/blog/2011/08/01/third-largest-bitcoin-exchange-bitomat-lost-their-wallet-over-17000-bitcoins-missing/). I would expect your problem to be something along this line. A rollback without corruption to a state some days ago is very very unlikely.

Comment: Based on the log, the crashed table looks like it was MyISAM.  As a DBA I generally stay far away from MyISAM tables because they are not as resilient as InnoDB, so I am not as familiar with their internal structures, but it seems plausible that a version of the table without the newest inserts could remain after a system crash, with potential interactions between filesystem recovery and MyISAM repair -- there *was* corruption, but it was repaired. Still, +1 ... the server in its current state likely has nothing left to "fix."

Comment: Possibly - I do SqlServer pretty much exclusively and it's file side structure is a lot more controlled, no file per table etc., so it can catch corruption. I would not really use that data at all - this is why backups are fundamental and I am pulling a differential on my core data every couple of minutes. At least on SQL Server log backups are fast and cheap (not a lot has changed in some minutes).